# Trouble obtaining detailed profile information about the job

Tags: upwork-api

I use this Upwork's endpoint '/api/profiles/v1/jobs/{job_key}.{format}' for getting detailed profile information about the job. Recently I got a problem by getting 'Forbidden: Freelancer profile is suspended' or 'Not Found: person is not found' errors when calling this endpoint with some job ids. For example: '~0150d301760bfe02d0'.
I suppose it has something to do with a fact that a client, whose job id I'm passing as an argument to the endpoint, may have history of dealing with freelancers which are now blocked or deleted.

I also made a little research to find out how many jobs on average have this problem. I took 100 random job ids, which corresponds to recently added jobs, and for each of them used endpoint for fetching info.

Here is code:

```
    const ids =
      '~01d946877182c141da;~0115f335daf0cb796a;~019312875ff7065097;~01019a0b4df5079dfa;~010776ccebe1af3ee7;~0132a3afde5ae04f8c;~01244a338fde1f542c;~01d2dd86560ce1d8f5;~0129de91d871876c55;~013b38348548c2d5a2;~0184ca442cc5aa0338;~0105f93bf4e6cbab7b;~01ac3d583c0d924016;~015aa57f33e078cbc1;~013f72b39a34adc16b;~01620f02054f562ba6;~015fa90b3b216e02e4;~01f5024a54b442982f;~016210cde00da339d7;~0182fa5a8dc65fdaf4;~01ffb8a25532a7a81f;~013c3dfcc0701e3edc;~01385d164c5f8c5fe8;~016434bcef8cb43718;~01c5a322dfa0da78b5;~01bb9768a93f8980b4;~0153508771ec0c5b10;~01f710e5be3c858c01;~01bbbbd21afa6d1f62;~0170622a6c106e2934;~01aa37e310f1c69007;~01aeb31a3cd79bedce;~014d5f93bbb9019c91;~01b5a1edfe354528e8;~0138b54510f98102d6;~0184bed8e653d54b40;~01fb5ec028d9257184;~01fda0c61c90afe5e8;~01eeb8fa08b089b3ca;~011600ade20967c924;~017f24677154f4dacb;~01596026f43a06031a;~015ddd11f455ccdcfc;~01dc757016c9bad4ff;~01042e56252ae68a02;~01e4bf704631f1afbf;~01ac8b1ff9e1259820;~01496ee864580d50ab;~017b60070b100f6374;~019706da23dde3bb76;~0148d0fedb046ad9e9;~015af1ed934f7245cd;~01c19b7f7febe0ff28;~0104fe970878a58e8c;~0109473bda35d39f24;~01f9cc2ae939160c64;~01ae6fc7c666df6b19;~01b4bea453edd934d1;~0153778b63e75a6ee5;~015e05ac9e0fb99ed0;~0194f369fe6e1d781b;~01864146f2e013db22;~012fdcefa0d86890d7;~0122c6a631cc25a436;~018e1fb83bca4cbd08;~01f6ab6172c3f3f497;~01158ba3e6371211e9;~0174259a7df833cd14;~01880a31539420951c;~01f88ea6af5a5bdd2c;~01a1e719099c699199;~01191ef6f72f1137c5;~01230be5fdcd455a1a;~0134c00eced3e92ec6;~018eedb0cb7621c45e;~0178562c4626f9aaaa;~01c36725615040f495;~01e0e946c325159fd5;~0184735318d4581527;~015071e22a928036dd;~01a1e719099c699199;~01191ef6f72f1137c5;~01230be5fdcd455a1a;~0134c00eced3e92ec6;~018eedb0cb7621c45e;~0178562c4626f9aaaa;~01c36725615040f495;~01e0e946c325159fd5;~0184735318d4581527;~015071e22a928036dd;~018d0da63832cf87ff;~0100b083be7d65d794;~01bea7bd9d919a5ce2;~012e8ba19388d2afae;~01b6a2ebc5ab6c4796;~01eec53908a6f09636;~0131559de010abd399;~0176a76793341135ce;~01ac1b0d5345a1f3ce;~01feecc7c797dd5bca;~01a1e719099c699199;~01230be5fdcd455a1a;~016d0e5588f0e91cd9;~01039cc9748df76a01;~01d37373980f8ce926;~0156c910d29536d88c;~01cdd73d45ff42d0c8;~01d5c732bd9a2dde95;~0134c00eced3e92ec6;~015bd703ccfb377a27;~01c36725615040f495;~01e0e946c325159fd5;~0184735318d4581527;~010d936a792efb4fda;~0158b1ccb5b3d23894;~018675c11cfa1c2c73;~015071e22a928036dd;~01615aca4a4b8b7667;~01ec7ff929c2d24b65;~014185ff1bbf9020ab'.split(
        ';',
      );

    const unique_ids = [...new Set(ids)].slice(0, 100);

    const result = await Promise.all(
      unique_ids.map((id) => this.upworkService.getSpecific(id)),
    );

    return result.reduce(
      (prev, curr) => {
        if (curr.error) {
          if (curr.error.message.includes('Freelancer profile is suspended')) {
            prev.errorFreelancerSuspended += 1;
          } else if (curr.error.message.includes('person is not found')) {
            prev.errorPersonNotFound += 1;
          } else {
            prev.otherErrors += 1;
          }
        } else prev.success += 1;

        return prev;
      },
      {
        success: 0,
        errorFreelancerSuspended: 0,
        errorPersonNotFound: 0,
        otherErrors: 0,
      },
    );
```

And here is a result:

```
{
  "success": 72,
  "errorFreelancerSuspended": 21,
  "errorPersonNotFound": 4,
  "otherErrors": 3
}
```

As you can see, nearly 25% of job from my sample have one of this errors. Of course it's not very representative research, but still enough to pay attention.

Is it intended behaviour or a bug? If it's intended then how can I handle such errors? I'm passing to this endpoint not one job id but multiple and error doesn't point which job id has this particular problem.
If it's a bug, when this can be fixed?